# How to fade background images (from CSS) in and out with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

As the question says I am trying to fade background images from one image to another for a few images.  I would like the initial image to appear immediately on page load, and then have it fade to the next image, then to the next, and back to the first, ongoing.

I have the background image in CSS:

```
.banner-image { 
background:transparent url('../images/8662834823_575a23516d_o.jpg') no-repeat center center;
-webkit-background-size:cover;
-moz-background-size:cover;
background-size:cover; 
height:800px; 
min-width: 1200px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="banner-image">

//Content here
</div>
```

I would like the banner-image div to maintain it's height (so other div's appear below it).  Which is why I want to maintain the images as CSS backgrounds.

How would I fade between images in jquery with the above requirements?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possible Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886870/fading-a-background-with-jquery

Comment: Why not use an image slider for this?  Especially if your `.banner-image` div is only going to display images.  Even if you need to place some text on top of this, it would be very doable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the simplest way to do this without a plugin: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PEgG4/5/)

Basically what I did here:

1. Created a parent `#bannerContainer` which has `position:relative;`
2. Added `position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;` to `.banner-image`.
3. Inserted a few `.banner-image` into the parent, giving each a different background image
4. Applied the following jQuery:

   ```
   $(function(){

       var t = setInterval(function(){

           $('.banner-image').last().fadeOut(2000,function(){ // 2 second fade duration
               $this = $(this);
               $parent = $this.parent();
               $this.remove().css('display','block'); // remove the faded element
               $parent.prepend($this); // put it as the first element
           });

       },3000); // every 3 seconds
   });
   ```

Markup:

```
<div id="bannerContainer">  
    <div class="banner-image"></div>
    <div class="banner-image" style="background-image:url(http://ns223506.ovh.net/rozne/00032cb2e758642ee9a942b49689f775/wallpaper-11152.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="banner-image" style="background-image:url(http://ns223506.ovh.net/rozne/9d1a802255f5c645945047acb4a2bac6/wallpaper-263.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="banner-image" style="background-image:url(http://ns223506.ovh.net/rozne/bd72cad0602bb9e53b4dc7f3fa4d4db9/wallpaper-4635.jpg)"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: and how do I have content appear over the images?

Comment: Best option is to wrap everything in another container, then adding an absolute container sibling to my code.. from there it's regular website programming

Comment: Also, I would like the images to take up the whole width of the page, they are not doing that now.  How do I do this?  I changed #bannerContainer to width 100%, and it's still not doing the entire page.

Comment: set also `.banner-image` as well as to the container to width:100%; height:100%;

Answer (score 1):

It is not a plug and play solution, but here is a JQuery code to change the background image with a `fadein` effect

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.banner-image').css({opacity: 0, background-image: 'url(../images/new.jpg)'}).fadeIn(2000);
});
```

Specify also some others CSS properties like `background-size` to maintain the ratio you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this demo - **Cross fading images using CSS3**

http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/